# Is there anyway to use a .txt file as a layout for printing to a Zebra Printer in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, txt, zebra-printers

To be short I am converting an old Dataflex print function to java in Android Studio. Now the function I am trying to replace takes a hard coded layout from a txt document, replaces all the underscores with variables and then sends it to the printer.
[image: This is what the .img file for the layout looks like:]

[image: Then the vars are named and assigned at run time]

Is there anyway to recreate this type of functionality in Java? My initial idea was of using a buffered reader to read a txt file and make a note of all of the instances of any underscores and replace these underscores with vars later, but this got confusing very fast. Any ideas or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly a use case for a templating language like Freemarker

Comment: I think you can download the text file to your android device and read the content of the file and pass that content directly to the printer